# Interpreting Normalization

Tags: statistics, linear-regression, normalization, scaling

1.) In linear regression, when the dependent variable is normalized (y - min/range) making it range from 0-1, can the output of the model be interpreted as probabilities?

For example if my dependent variable (y) is normalized, and I fit a linear regression model with numerical features/predictors, the predictions (y_hat) will also range from 0-1. My question is can I interpret this prediction as probabilities. Meaning >= 0.5 = success, and < 0.5 = failure.

2.) Another scenario: If both my dependent and independent variables are standardized ((value-min)/range) in a linear regression model, how do I interpret the model output?

3.) I developed a linear regression model with a normalized (y-min/range) dependent variable and standardized (x-mean/SD) features/covariates. When I test this model in a fresh dataset not used to train the model, do I also need to standardize the features/covariates in the testing data?

Also, how do I interpret the model output?

4.) If  both dependent (Y) and independent variables (X) are standardized (x-mean/SD), how is the model interpreted?

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here; better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

1. probably not, ordinary/OLS linear regressions go from -Inf to +Inf so you'd want to use a generalised linear regression parameterised with an appropriate "family" that provides the "link" between the +-Inf world of linear regressions and your [0,1] probability space.  R provides a "quasibinomial" family for this case, and uses a [logit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) function for this.
2. depends...  why are you "standardising"?  it's not needed like you'd do with a neural network. everything about the model is designed to be nicely convex and hence easy to optimise.  NNs tend not to be convex and hence much harder to optimise and so normalisation/standardisation is done to help things along
3. for the predictions to make sense you probably need to keep track of the transform (i.e. function & parameters) used with the original/training data and apply them to the test data.  if you standardise using the min/range from the test dataset then you'll probably be doing the wrong thing.  that said, there are situations when the converse is true, I'd encourage you to work through the maths to see how it applies to your situation
4. same as above, just moved around a bit.  coefficients are now just in terms of SDs from the mean, but again it's probably easier working with units that aid interpretation

https://stats.stackexchange.com might be a better place for these sorts of questions...